# intelliJ android UI rendering problems - Missing Library

Tags: android, intellij-idea, intellij-13

After much headbashing i seem to have got my first hello world app running within IntelliJ ultimate. I downloaded the lastest ultimate edition today.

When I try and open the main.xml in the UI designer I get the error below.

Can anyone help? I liked the look of the UI designer from the videos that intelliJ provider here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/android-tutorials.jsp

Thanks in advance

```
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA

org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:149)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:167)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:485)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to choose API 19 instead of 20 in the dropdown list.

Comment: Hi @PanWrona. I will check later today. Out of interest what dropdown do you mean?

Comment: You have some options above the design window, such as choosing device type, device position(landscape or portrait) and as I mentioned before - API dropdown list, where you can choose the API version

Comment: Does community edition support this? 

I'm having the same problem as OP, but I can't select a different render version. The dropdown list only contains "Automatically Pick Best".

Comment: Hmm I've never used the community release so I think I can't help you :(

Answer (score 13):

In the preview tab simply open the last drop-down list and pick the lower Android SDK. In my case, I picked Android 4.4.2 and the preview appeared instantly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA

> You can find the answer in error,follow this line and update your idea 14 ultimate this is new version of intellij

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ihsanbal. From this link http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ version 13 is the latest. Where are you get 14 from?

Comment: From this link : http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP There are two different versions 'Community Edition' and 'Ultimate' my suggestion you choose Ultimate.

Comment: thanks @ihsanbal. I think this would solve it but I'd rather not take an EAP. It took me long enough to set everything else up ;)